# How to run queries from MongooseIM module

Tags: erlang, mongoose-im

I am trying to make MongooseIM module, that will trigger with offline_message_hook, count number of pending messages in offline storage for the user and send it to an URL through GET method. Below is my code.

```
send_notice(From, To, Packet) ->
    Type = xml:get_tag_attr_s(list_to_binary("type"), Packet),
    Body = xml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, list_to_binary("body")}, cdata]),
    PostUrl = "http://myurl.com/",
    Count = count_msg(To),
    GetParam = "?count=",
    FullUrl = PostUrl ++ GetParam ++ Count,

    ?DEBUG("POST URL : ~s",[FullUrl]),

    if (Type == <<"chat">>) and (Body /= <<"">>) ->
              Sep = "&",
        Post = [
          "alert=", url_encode(binary_to_list(Body)), Sep,
                                        "badge=", url_encode("+1"), Sep,
          % "sound=", Sound, Sep,
          "channel=", To#jid.luser, Sep,
          "info[from]=", From#jid.luser, Sep],
          % "auth_token=", Token],

        ?INFO_MSG("Sending post request to ~s with body \"~s\"", [FullUrl, Post]),

        httpc:request(post, {binary_to_list(FullUrl), [], "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", list_to_binary(Post)},[],[]),
        ok;
      true ->
        ok
    end.

count_msg(To) ->
     Username = To#jid.luser,
     LServer = To#jid.lserver,
     Count = ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
      LServer,
      ["select count(*) from offline_message "
       "where username='", Username, "';"]),
     ?DEBUG("Count = ~s",[Count]),
     Count.
```

When I run it I get the below errors

```
2015-03-09 16:37:11.598 [debug] <0.763.0>@mod_zeropush:count_msg:102 FORMAT ERROR: "Count = ~s" [{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}]
["select count(*) from offline_message where username='",<<"reader">>,"';"]
2015-03-09 16:37:11.599 [debug] <0.763.0>@mod_zeropush:send_notice:72 FORMAT ERROR: "POST URL : ~s" [[104,116,116,112,58,47,47,107,107,104,97,110,46,100,108,99,119,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,46,99,111,109,47,63,99,111,117,110,116,61|{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}]]
2015-03-09 16:37:11.599 [info] <0.763.0>@mod_zeropush:send_notice:84 FORMAT ERROR: "Sending post request to ~s with body \"~s\"" [[104,116,116,112,58,47,47,107,107,104,97,110,46,100,108,99,119,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,46,99,111,109,47,63,99,111,117,110,116,61|{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}],["alert=","xxx","&","badge=","%2B1","&","channel=",<<"reader">>,"&","info[from]=",<<"kkhan">>,"&"]]
2015-03-09 16:37:11.602 [error] <0.763.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run1:240 {badarg,[{erlang,binary_to_list,[[104,116,116,112,58,47,47,107,107,104,97,110,46,100,108,99,119,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,46,99,111,109,47,63,99,111,117,110,116,61|{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}]],[]},{mod_zeropush,send_notice,3,[{file,"src/mod_zeropush.erl"},{line,86}]},{safely,apply,3,[{file,"src/safely.erl"},{line,19}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,236}]},{ejabberd_sm,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,108}]},{ejabberd_local,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},{line,139}]},{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,78}]},{ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,1098}]}]}
```

Whats the proper way to fetch SQL query results in erlang? and what format does httpc:request expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you get are not exactly SQL or MongooseIM specific errors. They are erroneous uses of `io_lib:format/2` or a similar string formatting function.

This error:

```
2015-03-09 16:37:11.598 [debug] <0.763.0>@mod_zeropush:count_msg:102 FORMAT ERROR: "Count = ~s" [{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}]
```

relates to:

```
?DEBUG("Count = ~s", [Count])
```

But `Count` is neither a string, nor a binary, nor an iolist, nor an atom (only these types can be printed using `~s` - the string formatting character; refer to [`man io` function `format/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-3)).
For printing complex terms using the default Erlang term syntax please use `~p` or `~w`.

All your `FORMAT ERROR` errors are of this kind - you're using a wrong format specifier for the data type you pass in.

OK, so what is the format of a SQL query result? It's printed in one of the error lines:

```
{selected, [<<"count">>], [{<<"5">>}]}
```

This is a simple transliteration from what you would get in a SQL shell (this example comes from a random table I had at hand in PostgreSQL):

```
> SELECT count(*) FROM conversation_state;
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

Here's an equivalent run from an Erlang shell:

```
> ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(<<"localhost">>, ["SELECT count(*) FROM conversation_state;"]).
{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"2">>}]}
```

So the result is always a 3-tuple; the first element being `selected` (or `inserted`, `updated`... depending on the query); the second element being a list of column headers (here there's just one column `count`); the third element being a list of tuples, where each tuple corresponds to one row of the result set. Elements of the rows-as-tuples are in the same order as the column headers.

About the last error:

```
2015-03-09 16:37:11.602 [error] <0.763.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run1:240 {badarg,[{erlang,binary_to_list,[[104,116,116,112,58,47,47,107,107,104,97,110,46,100,108,99,119,111,114,108,100,119,105,100,101,46,99,111,109,47,63,99,111,117,110,116,61|{selected,[<<"count">>],[{<<"5">>}]}]],[]},{mod_zeropush,send_notice,3,[{file,"src/mod_zeropush.erl"},{line,86}]},{safely,apply,3,[{file,"src/safely.erl"},{line,19}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,236}]},{ejabberd_sm,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_sm.erl"},{line,108}]},{ejabberd_local,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_local.erl"},{line,139}]},{ejabberd_router,route,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_router.erl"},{line,78}]},{ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,1098}]}]}
```

You're trying to pass a list created with `FullUrl = PostUrl ++ GetParam ++ Count` to `erlang:binary_to_list/1`. As the name implies, this function takes binaries, not lists. Erlang is **dynamically, but strongly typed** and there are few implicit type conversions. Unpack the result of the SQL query properly, return just the number from `count_msg` and build the HTTP request URL from that.